# if given $3^{6x}+3^{-6x}+3^{2x+1}+3^{-2x+2} = 27 $, then the value of $ \frac{2(a+b)}{3^{a} + 3^{b}}$ where a and b is roots of the given.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, logarithms, roots, exponentiation

I never learned this in class.
Given:
$$3^{6x}+3^{-6x}+3^{2x+1}+3^{-2x+2} = 27
$$
If a and b are the solutions, then the value of:
$$ \frac{2(a+b)}{3^{a} + 3^{b}}$$
are ....?

I tried to let $p=3^{2x}$, then the equation become $p^3 + \frac{1}{p^3} + 3p + \frac{9}{p} = 27$, and multiplying this with (p³):
$$ p^6 + 3p^4 - 27p^3 + 9p^2+1=0$$
And finally, i stuck here.
Give any idea to help me, please?

Comment: Hint expand $(3^{2x}+3^{-2x})^3$ and see what terms remain missing from your LHS, then substitute $3^{2x}=t$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but I confuse myself with what I wrote"? E.g. Show your work. As hinted at, your approach works, and you just need to push it through.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try it and I will let you know when I find the answer.